# grails 3.0.x jquery-ui datepicker

Tags: grails, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm a Grails newbie. I can see lots of examples of Grails 2.x and jquery-ui but none for Grails 3.0.x. Can someone possibly provide an example of how to include jquery-ui and user a date-picker in a Grails 3.0.x environment please and the steps to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use Grails for that. You should use bower for that purpose. Install node.js and than Bower. Use it to install ant JS dependencies to your project. And then just include it to gsp pages.